# How can I replace a prefab with existing objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The method do replacing the prefab with the existing objects but in some situations it's not doing it right.

For example when I have in the Hierarchy a parent object and two childs:

```
Cube
  Cube1
  Cube2
```

If I will replace Cube with the prefab it will delete the Cube,Cube1,Cube2 and will create the new prefab.

But I want it to replace only the Cube with the prefab and keep the childs Cube1 and Cube2 as they are and as childs of Cube.

And If for example I will select Cube and Cube2 then replace Cube and Cube2 but keep the parent and childs as they are:

```
Prefab
   Cube1
   Prefab
```

Or

```
Prefab
   Prefab
   Prefab
```

The idea is to keep the parent/childs structure.

The method:

```
private void InstantiatePrefab(List<GameObject> selection)
    {
        if (prefab != null && selection.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                var selected = selection[i];
                SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(selected.scene.name));

                var prefabType = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType(prefab);
                GameObject newObject;

                if (prefabType == PrefabType.Prefab)
                {
                    newObject = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefab);
                }
                else
                {
                    newObject = Instantiate(prefab);
                    newObject.name = prefab.name;
                }
                if (newObject == null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Error instantiating prefab");
                    break;
                }

                Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(newObject, "Replace With Prefabs");
                newObject.transform.parent = selected.transform.parent;
                newObject.transform.localPosition = selected.transform.localPosition;
                newObject.transform.localRotation = selected.transform.localRotation;
                newObject.transform.localScale = selected.transform.localScale;
                newObject.transform.SetSiblingIndex(selected.transform.GetSiblingIndex());
                Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(selected);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
void OnGUI()
{
  var selection = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToList();
  InstantiatePrefab(selection);
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this.